# Get the RowCount as a new column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the count of ComponentSubTypes for each SpecificationID. Currently, I am getting the total count. How can the count be separated for each SpecificationID. Could anyone please help? Can this be handled in SSIS script component?

I tried this.

```
select  P.SpecificationID, CT.ComponentType,cst.ComponentSubType from [LSCDATA].[Product] P
join LSCDATA.Component C on P.SpecificationID = C.ProductSpecificationID
join LSCMASTER.ComponentType CT on C.ComponentTypeID = CT.ComponentTypeID
join LSCMASTER.ComponentSubType cst on c.ComponentSubTypeID  = cst.ComponentSubTypeID
where cst.ComponentSubType = 'Tab' and p.SpecificationID in 
(242996,20281,80530,52357,726480,2441)
order by p.SpecificationID

select  @@ROWCOUNT as Num
```

And got the result like this.

[image]

But I want the result to be like

```
 SpecificationID   NumberOfTabs
    20281              2
    52357              1
    80530              1
    242996             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To use Group by :

```
select  P.SpecificationID, count(CT.ComponentType) from [LSCDATA].[Product] P
join LSCDATA.Component C on P.SpecificationID = C.ProductSpecificationID
join LSCMASTER.ComponentType CT on C.ComponentTypeID = CT.ComponentTypeID
join LSCMASTER.ComponentSubType cst on c.ComponentSubTypeID  = cst.ComponentSubTypeID
where cst.ComponentSubType = 'Tab' and p.SpecificationID in 
(242996,20281,80530,52357,726480,2441)
group by p.SpecificationID
order by p.SpecificationID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SpecificationId)" into your project list to get what you are requesting

Answer (score 0):

You already filtered only Tabs, so you can just use count the rows:

```
SELECT  P.SpecificationID   AS  SpecificationID,
        COUNT(*)            AS  NumberOfTabs

FROM    [LSCDATA].[Product]         AS  P
JOIN    LSCDATA.Component           AS  C   ON P.SpecificationID = C.ProductSpecificationID
JOIN    LSCMASTER.ComponentType     AS  CT  ON C.ComponentTypeID = CT.ComponentTypeID
JOIN    LSCMASTER.ComponentSubType  AS  cst ON c.ComponentSubTypeID  = cst.ComponentSubTypeID

WHERE   cst.ComponentSubType        =   'Tab'
AND     p.SpecificationID           IN  (242996,20281,80530,52357,726480,2441)

GROUP BY    p.SpecificationID
ORDER by    p.SpecificationID
```